# Block file writing in external drives

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I am working on a project for my company and I have reached a dead end.
I am trying to find a way to be able to decide whether to allow or block file writing to an external drive based on the content written.

The project is creating a basic DLP system.

I have tried using `pydbg` to debug Windows explorer, this worked partially but was very unstable and it doesn't work globally (ex. file write with `cmd`).

The solution can be in any language (`Python` preferred).

Any kind of help would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure I can see a way to do this without writing a filter driver. You won't be able to do that in Python.

Comment: @DavidCullen Python is not a must. There is no way to maybe to a system wide `WriteFile` hooking for example?

Comment: I see code for hooking WriteFile in a Google search